# How to get conform box selected value vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How to get selected value from vscode model.I did but not working.ANyone find where i did mistake.If i select yes pick value should be yes but not working.I am getting [object.Promise] error.How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question i guess you are facing issue by lack of promise handling. Please confirm your **showWarningMessage** function returning promise or not. If promise then please do these changes.

```
vscode.window.showWarningMessage(message, { modal: true }, yes).then(pick =>{
  if (pick === yes) {
     vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Success");
   } else {
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Canceled");
   }
});
```